# C++: Mastermind game two players

Tags: c++

I have made an attempt to write the *[Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29#Gameplay_and_rules)* game, to improve my basics in C++. I would like my code reviewed, emphasising on design, readability and structure of the program.

The secret code is stored as a string of 4 character/PEGS and input is taken as: `RRGY` for `red red green yellow`.

```
#define RED "\x1b[31;1m"
#define GREEN "\x1b[32;1m"
#define YELLOW "\x1b[33;1m"
#define BLUE "\x1b[34;1m"
#define MAGENTA "\x1b[35;1m"
#define CYAN "\x1b[36;1m"
#define WHITE "\x1b[37;1m"
#define RESET "\x1b[0m"

void printCode(const std::string &code);
bool isMatching(const std::string &code, std::string &userCode);
inline void showMoves(std::vector<std::string> &prevMoves);
void readCode(std::string &code);
void setup(unsigned int &maxGames, unsigned int &maxGuess);


const unsigned int PEGS = 4;
```

**main()**

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int maxGuess, maxGames, p1score, p2score;
    setup(maxGames, maxGuess);

    for (int game = 0; game != maxGames; ++game)
    {
        bool won = false;
        int score = 0;
        std::string secretCode;
        //keeps track of all the previous moves and feedback.
        std::vector<std::string> prevMoves;

        std::cout << "New Game\nSet secret code: ";
        readCode(secretCode);

        for (int guess = 1; guess != maxGuess + 1; ++guess)
        {
            std::cout << "guess: " << guess << " / "
                      << maxGuess << "\n";

            std::string userCode;
            std::cout << "Code: ";
            readCode(userCode);
            score++;

            if (isMatching(secretCode, userCode))
            {
                won = true;
                std::cout << WHITE << "Code successfully broken!\n";
                printCode(secretCode);
                break;
            }

            // Update previous moves and display them.
            prevMoves.push_back(userCode);
            showMoves(prevMoves);
        }

        if (!won)
        {
            std::cout << "Oops! You were unable"
                      << " to crack the code\n";
            printCode(secretCode);
        }

        if (score == maxGuess)
            score++;

        // if current game is an even number then update
        // player 1's score.
        if (game % 2 != 0)
        {
            p1score = score;
            std::cout << "Player 1: " << p1score << "\n\n";
        }

        else
        {
            p2score = score;
            std::cout << "Player 2: " << p2score << "\n\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n\nPlayer 1: " << p1score << '\n'
              << "Player 2: " << p2score << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

**setup()**

```
void setup(unsigned int &maxGames, unsigned int &maxGuess)
{
    std::cout << "Max Games: ";
    std::cin >> maxGames;
    std::cout << "Max turns: ";
    std::cin >> maxGuess;

    try
    {
        if(maxGames % 2 != 0 || maxGuess % 2 != 0)
            throw std::range_error("Invalid number!");

        if(maxGames > 12 || maxGuess > 12)
            throw std::overflow_error("Number too high!");
    }

    catch(std::range_error err)
    {
        std::cout << err.what()
                  << "\nNumber should be even!\n"
                  << "Try again\n\n";

        setup(maxGames, maxGuess);
    }

    catch(std::overflow_error err)
    {
        std::cout << err.what()
                  << "\nNumber should be less than 13\n"
                  << "Try again\n\n";

        setup(maxGames, maxGuess);
    }
}
```

**showMoves()**

```
inline void showMoves(std::vector<std::string> &prevMoves)
{
    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = prevMoves.begin();
         i != prevMoves.end(); ++i)
        printCode(*i);
}
```

**readCode()**

```
void readCode(std::string &code)
{
    std::cin >> code;
    try
    {
        if(code.size() != PEGS)
            throw std::length_error("Invalid number of characters!");

        for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i != PEGS; ++i)
            if(code[i] != 'R' && code[i] != 'G' && code[i] != 'B' &&
               code[i] != 'Y' &&code[i] != 'M' && code[i] != 'C' && code[i] != '-')
               throw std::range_error("Invalid colours!");
    }

    catch(std::length_error err)
    {
        std::cout << "\n\n" << err.what() << '\n'
                  << "Permitted characters " << PEGS
                  << "\nTry again: ";

        readCode(code);
    }

    catch(std::range_error err)
    {
        std::cout << "\n\n" << err.what() << '\n'
                   << "Permitted colours: "
                   << "R G B Y M C -\n"
                   << "Try again: ";

        readCode(code);
    }
    system("clear");
    return ;
}
```

**printCode()**

```
void printCode(std::string const &code)
{
    std::string::size_type i = 0;

    while (i != code.size())
    {
        switch (code[i++])
        {
        case 'R':
            std::cout << RED << "# ";
            break;
        case 'G':
            std::cout << GREEN << "# ";
            break;
        case 'Y':
            std::cout << YELLOW << "# ";
            break;
        case 'B':
            std::cout << BLUE << "# ";
            break;
        case 'M':
            std::cout << MAGENTA << "# ";
            break;
        case 'C':
            std::cout << CYAN << "# ";
            break;
        case 'P':
            std::cout << WHITE << " P";
            break;
        case 'O':
            std::cout << WHITE << " O";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "  ";
        }
    }

    std::cout << RESET << '\n';
}
```

**isMatching()**

```
bool isMatching(const std::string &secretCode, std::string &userCode)
{
    // keeps track of the duplicates, so that feedback
    // is not provided twice for a single colour.
    std::vector<bool> seenCode(4, false);
    std::vector<bool> seenUserCode(seenCode);

    std::string feedback;
    std::string::size_type i, j;

    // for each character in the userCode, update the feedback
    // with the character 'P' if they match both in colour
    // and position with the secret code. 
    for (i = 0; i != PEGS; ++i)
    {
        if (secretCode[i] == userCode[i])
        {
            feedback += 'P';
            seenCode[i] = seenUserCode[i] = true;
        }
    }

    // for each character in the userCode, update the feedback
    // with the character 'O', if they match in colour but not in
    // position with the secret code.
    for (i = 0; i != PEGS; ++i)
    {
        if (!seenCode[i])
        {
            for (j = 0; j != PEGS; ++j)
            {
                if (!seenUserCode[j] && secretCode[i] == userCode[j])
                {
                    seenUserCode[j] = true;
                    feedback += 'O';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // concatenate the userCode with feedback.
    userCode += feedback;

    // if the userCode did not match the code.
    if (feedback != "PPPP")
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

I plan to add **rules** and **how to play** files later on.

Comment: You have a typo in the second line from `main`: you typed in a colon `:` instead of a semi-colon `;`.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Phrancis but the accepted answer is for the edited question and not the current one.

Comment: I apologize for not noticing that, I have undone the rollback. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Comment: No problem. It was actually my fault for editing the code after posting it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I love the UI! Good job. But, there are a few (major) things that you can do better.

#### Where are the `#include`s?

Either you didn't paste them here (you should always post the whole code BTW), or you haven't included them. That's bad! Some compilers will happily compile your code even if you are missing some `#include`s, but that is not standard behavior.

When I compiled your code, I was greeted with *a lot* of errors, all related to missing headers.

#### Don't use macros when you can use variables

Macros are bad, but in some cases they are necessary, because there is no viable alternative. But not in your case. You could easily replace those "constants" with actual variables:

```
constexpr auto RED = "\x1b[31;1m";
constexpr auto GREEN = "\x1b[32;1m";
constexpr auto YELLOW = "\x1b[33;1m";
constexpr auto BLUE = "\x1b[34;1m";
constexpr auto MAGENTA = "\x1b[35;1m";
constexpr auto CYAN = "\x1b[36;1m";
constexpr auto WHITE = "\x1b[37;1m";
constexpr auto RESET = "\x1b[0m";
```

#### Don't declare variables at the top of functions if they are needed later

Always declare variables in the smallest scope possible, and never *ever* declare every variable used in a function at the top of it. That's bad for several reasons:

- You might initialize a variable that is expensive to create, only to not use it because the function returned prematurely.
- You might accidentally change a value of a variable that you shouldn't have changed.
- You might forget to initialize some variables (which you did - see `isMatching`), leaving them in an unspecified state. If you forget that the variable doesn't have a value yet, you will have a (possible) hard time debugging.

#### Listen to the compiler warnings!

Always listen to the compiler warnings, and always compile with a high warning level.

You have 3 warnings that can easily be fixed:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:29:29: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     for (int game = 0; game != maxGames; ++game)
                        ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:40:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         for (int guess = 1; guess != maxGuess + 1; ++guess)
                             ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:70:19: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         if (score == maxGuess)
```

#### `std::...::size_type` is also known as `std::size_t` (within reasons)

`std::size_t` is required to be able to store the maximum size of *any* type. This means that `std::size_t` is either larger or equal to `std::...::size_type`. In fact, in most cases, `size_type` is a synonym:

> When indexing C++ containers, such as `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc, the appropriate type is the member typedef `size_type` provided by such containers. It is usually defined as a synonym for **`std::size_t`**.

<sup>Taken from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).</sup>

This can save you some typing :)

#### Why `inline`?

Why is `showMoves` inline? It really doesn't need to be inline, as it is declared inside a translation unit, and thus can't be used anywhere else, which is the whole point of `inline`! You should declare a function as `inline` to enable the compiler to better optimize it as the definition of the function will be available in every translation unit using it.

Contrary of what you might think, declaring a function `inline` doesn't make the compiler inline your function. It does this whether you declared it `inline` or not. It can also ignore the `inline` keyword, as it might deem the function unsuitable for inlining.

#### Catch exceptions by `const&`

If you don't catch exceptions by reference, you will see unexpected behavior if an exception is thrown that inherits that specific exception. This is called [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). Making it `const` is better because it prevents you have actually modifying the exception if you didn't mean to (this can be applied to every variable - see [const correctness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136880/sell-me-on-const-correctness)).

#### Prefer returning a value than passing a reference

You should write functions that return a new value, instead of modifying a value passed as a parameter. The reason being, is that you never want your variables to be in an unspecified state, and if you pass be ref, you will need to write 2 lines instead of 1 when initializing it, possibly leaving it uninitialized for a short amount of time.

```
// 2 lines
std::string secretCode;
readCode(secretCode);

// 1 line
std::string secretCode = readCode();
```

With the advent of move semantics and RVO, there won't be any string copied, it will be moved, which is very cheap. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics).

#### Use `<` instead of `!=`

In every loop that you have, you have `var != end` or similar constructs. If you accidentally increment `var` *past* `end`, the loop will continue running. Instead, if you would have used `var < end`, then the loop will still terminate.

Sometimes, this is not possible, for example with iterators, which don't have an `operator<`.

#### You can inline `setup`

`setup` functions are very controversial. I would advocate to *not* using them, as if you for some reason forget to call them, you will get strange results.

The recursion of `setup` can be easily changed into a `while` loop, which has the added advantaged of not overflowing the stack if a user enters the wrong numbers to many times.

#### Some general questions

Why does the number of games have to be even? Same for the number of guesses? Is there any practical reason why I can't play 1 or 3 games? Or why I can't specify 5 guesses?

I think you should drop those requirements, but I might be missing something.

#### Const correctness

Use `const` whenever possible, as stated previously above. `showMoves` doesn't change its first parameter `prevMoves`, so why not make it `const`? That way, someone using that function will know that the passed container will not be modified. Without `const`, people (including you some time in the future) will be vary of using that function because of the possible side effects that is has.

#### Use `auto` and for each loops

You can use `auto` to reduce a few variable definitions:

```
std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = prevMoves.begin();
```

becomes

```
auto i = prevMoves.cbegin(); // note the c, stands for const
```

At the same time, you can use for each loops:

```
 for (auto i = prevMoves.cbegin(); i != prevMoves.cend(); ++i)
    printCode(*i);
```

becomes

```
 for (const auto& value : prevMoves)
     printCode(value);
```

#### Variable names

You should only use `i` and `j` for small loops, not anything more. Always use better names if you can. Also, `ALL_CAPS_VARIABLES` should only be used for macros, and not for constant variables.

#### Unnecessary `return` statements

You can omit `return 0;` in `main`, as the compiler automatically "adds" it.

`return;` statements as last statements in a function returning `void` is unnecessary, as the function will already return if there is no more statement.

#### Don't use platform dependent code

`std::system("clear");` is a typical example of platform dependent code. If I were to run your code on a Windows machine, it will not work. Why? Because the clear command on Windows is called `cls`, and not `clear`. You should try to avoid any platform dependent code whenever possible, and provide alternatives if you can't (using macros).

Also, coloring the terminal is not supported for every terminal, so you might want to disable colors if the terminal doesn't support it.

#### Let's shorten `printCode`!

This is completely optional, but I would prefer this `printCode` implementation:

```
void printCode(std::string const &code)
{
    static std::unordered_map<char, std::string> map = {
        { 'R', "\x1b[31;1m# " }, // red
        { 'G', "\x1b[32;1m# " }, // green
        { 'Y', "\x1b[33;1m# " }, // yellow
        { 'B', "\x1b[34;1m# " }, // blue
        { 'M', "\x1b[35;1m# " }, // magenta
        { 'C', "\x1b[36;1m# " }, // cyan
        { 'P', "\x1b[37;1m P" }, // white
        { 'O', "\x1b[37;1m O" }  // white
    };

    for (auto ch : code)
        std::cout << (map.find(std::toupper(ch)) != map.end() ? map[std::toupper(ch)] : "  ");
    std::cout << "\x1b[0m" << '\n';
    // you might notice that I don't use any of the constants
    // that's because this is the only place where you are using them
    // so you might as well inline them
}
```

Just because it's short and readable :)

Comment: Wonderful! I will keep these suggestions in mind and change the existing code. Also the number of games is even so that both the players get to make and break the code same number of times. The compiler warnings did not appear on compiling, perhaps (if you are using g++) have the -Wall option turned on ?

Comment: You might want to note that terminal-specific escape codes also come into the category of "platform-dependent code".  You don't know what terminal (or emulator) your users will have, so get those values from elsewhere.  A library such as Curses may be more convenient than directly calling reading termcap entries, of course.

Comment: @CaptainDaVinci Yes, I am using the `-Wall` flag, but you should too, as you'll maybe catch some bugs :)

Comment: @TobySpeight That's true, although Curses is also platform dependent :) Thanks though.